# How to use cmder mini instead default cmd in Visual Studio (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cmd

When I run my node.js application in Visual Studio 2013, then launches the default console (cmd). I prefer **CMDER MINI**, how can I change default console to cmder mini in my visual studio?

Comment: You can use **COMSPEC** environment variable, VS Code is supposed to honour it but it doesn't work: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5874, I tried with Cmder and Git Bash.